# Unix Shell scripting (KSH)

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Can we create dynamic arrays in Ksh?
like, can we create array_$i[] arrays where i ranges from 1 to 5? i.e., array_1[], array_2[],array_3[], array_4[] and array_5[]

so that I can iterate through array_$i.
Is that possible in ksh?

Comment: if you can't, you should be able to emulate it with `eval`.

Comment: Could you please illustrate how to use eval? Also, how to access the array elements? ${array_$arr[$i]} doesn't work I believe?

Comment: If you need rich data structures, a shell scripting language is the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `eval`

```
eval array_$i'[$j]=$val'
eval 'echo $array_'$i
```

Answer (score 0):

In ksh93, you can create compound variables.  These are really hashes, not arrays, but can be used as such, when using numeric indexes.

```
$ $ echo $KSH_VERSION
Version JM 93u 2011-02-08
$ a[1][1]=foo
$ a[3][1]=bar
$ print -C a
([1]=([1]=foo) [3]=([1]=bar) )
$ print -v a
(
    [1]=(
                    [1]=foo
    )
    [3]=(
                    [1]=bar
    )
)
$ print ${a[1][1]} 
foo
$ print ${a[3][1]}
bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Henk, but the ksh we are using is of version 88. But need to create dynamic arrays if possible. using eval, it's becoming possible to assign values. however, am still facing issue to iterate in a loop.

Comment: There aren't that many Unixen around that only do ksh88. Which platform is that?  Some, like IBM, have both, with a separate ksh93 binary.  Anyway, the eval would work, but I'd move to awk/perl/python/ksh93 - whatever is available, even if I'd have to install it myself.

Answer (score 0):

To develop more Bamar's answer here is an example of how those "arrays" could be used in ksh:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

#--------------------------------------
# populate arrays

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do  # here we will define/use 5 arrays

    count=$RANDOM%10   # random array size up to 10 elements

    while [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; do

        let count=$count-1
        eval my_arrays_${i}[$count]=$RANDOM  # assigning some random numbers to the array elements

    done


done

#--------------------------------------
# display arrays content
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
    idx=0
    arr_name=my_arrays_${i}
    arr_name_cnt="\${#$arr_name[*]}"
    eval count=$arr_name_cnt  # getting the array count of elements
    echo "Array $arr_name has $count elements"
    while [[ $idx -lt $count ]]; do   # loop over array elements
        arr_elem="\${${arr_name}[$idx]}"
        eval arr_elem=$arr_elem   # getting the actual value of the array element
        echo "Element $idx: < $arr_elem > "
        let idx+=1
    done
done
```